# VS Code auto suggest selection not working as expected on pressing enter or tab

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

VS Code syntax and variable suggestions are not working proper on clicking enter or tab. Whenever it suggest variable/syntax I click enter, Ideally it should autocomplete but cursor goes in new line without completing suggestion. When I click tab cursor goes end of the line.

I use `IntelliCode` extension too. It was working proper before but not right now for unknown reasons. Why isn't it working now?

Comment: 1) what's the value of your `editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter` setting? 2) have you configured any keyboard shortcuts that could be interfering with this?

Comment: 3) Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: @user, Thanks mate. `editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter` was not there in my `settings.json` file, It worked now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the enter key, the default value of the `editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter` is `"on"`, so you might have accidentally set it to `"off"` somewhere (user or workspace [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson)). I'd suggest to first look for where that happens and delete that. Otherwise you can add a line that says `"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "on"`.

I'm not sure why your tab key wouldn't be working. It might be that you're trying to perform suggestion completions inside a snippet context, where tab is used to jump between fields of the snippet.

Otherwise, I'd check for other keyboard shortcuts that could be interfering with enter or tab for suggestion acceptance, or do [an extension bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to see if an extension is causing the issue. See also the [keyboard issue troubleshooting wiki](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues#troubleshoot).